# I get this shutdown prompt, then my laptop dies. What is happening?

Tags: linux-mint, shutdown, crash

I get a dialog box that says 'Shut down the system now', the same as if I had clicked 'quit' in the main menu.  This happens seemingly randomly.  If I choose 'cancel', it sometimes goes away.  Other times,it pops back up again.  Whether or not I click cancel, my laptop will shutdown immediately, as if all the power has gone.  When I run 'last -x', I see this:

```
korgan   pts/1        :0               Sat Jul 27 07:32   still logged in   
korgan   tty8         :0               Sat Jul 27 06:57   still logged in   
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.5.0-17-generic Sat Jul 27 06:57 - 07:42  (00:44)    
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-17-generic Sat Jul 27 06:57 - 07:42  (00:44)    
korgan   pts/1        :0               Fri Jul 26 20:27 - 21:13  (00:46)    
korgan   pts/1        :0               Fri Jul 26 17:05 - 18:07  (01:02)    
korgan   tty8         :0               Fri Jul 26 17:02 - crash  (13:54)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.5.0-17-generic Fri Jul 26 17:02 - 06:57  (13:54)    
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-17-generic Fri Jul 26 17:02 - 07:42  (14:39)    
shutdown system down  3.5.0-17-generic Fri Jul 26 17:02 - 17:02  (00:00)    
shutdown system down  3.5.0-17-generic Fri Jul 26 17:01 - 17:02  (00:00)    
runlevel (to lvl 6)   3.5.0-17-generic Fri Jul 26 17:01 - 17:01  (00:00)    
korgan   tty8         :0               Fri Jul 26 16:20 - 17:01  (00:41)    
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.5.0-17-generic Fri Jul 26 16:19 - 17:01  (00:41)    
reboot   system boot  3.5.0-17-generic Fri Jul 26 16:19 - 17:01  (00:41)
```

There is a 'crash' entry at 13:54 on the 26th, although the crash that happened last night was before the reboot the following day, the 27th.

I've checked the temperature of the cpu when I get this prompt and it's nothing irregular, usually around 52 °C.  I don't know what my next step should be.  I'm running Linux Mint 14 on a Gateway NV53A.

I looked at `/var/log/syslog` and I found this, at the point of shutdown:

```
Jul 27 09:29:39 Ono-Sendai kernel: [ 9146.988498] type=1701 audit(1374935379.026:3114): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=5729 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=2 compat=0 ip=0x7f368d4f96c0 code=0x50000
Jul 27 09:29:39 Ono-Sendai kernel: [ 9146.988507] type=1701 audit(1374935379.026:3115): auid=4294967295 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=4294967295 pid=5729 comm="chrome" reason="seccomp" sig=0 syscall=2 compat=0 ip=0x7f368d4f96c0 code=0x50000
Jul 27 09:31:13 Ono-Sendai kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jul 27 09:31:13 Ono-Sendai rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="619" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Jul 27 09:31:13 Ono-Sendai rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai bluetoothd[672]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai bluetoothd[672]: Starting SDP server
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai bluetoothd[672]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai bluetoothd[672]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai bluetoothd[672]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai bluetoothd[672]: Failed to init time plugin
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai bluetoothd[672]: Failed to init alert plugin
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai bluetoothd[672]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai avahi-daemon[699]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 111) and group 'avahi' (GID 120).
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai avahi-daemon[699]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai avahi-daemon[699]: avahi-daemon 0.6.31 starting up.
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai avahi-daemon[699]: Successfully called chroot().
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai avahi-daemon[699]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Jul 27 09:31:14 Ono-Sendai kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 3.5.0-17-generic (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) ) #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 (Ubuntu 3.5.0-17.28-generic 3.5.5)
```

Comment: Do you get the same behavior regardless of the desktop environment/window manager you're using?

Comment: @JosephR. I haven't tested that yet, however, I think it may be a hardware problem.  My case is damaged and, I notice if the screen is pushed back too far, it happens.  :/

Comment: I would guess it's a hardware problem, something is causing the power button to be falsely triggered and held for a few seconds (which will forcefully power the system off).